# Thymeleaf th:each and multiple modals, how to make it work correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, thymeleaf

I have to trigger different modals in the same page based on an object.id in a th:each loop, this is my code.
I can't find any mistakes, but when I try it always trigger just the last modal and I don't understand why...
I can't use bootstrap for that and I understand the very basic of Javascript. It would be nice if someone knows where I'm wrong and could help me with this.
Thank you

```js
// Get the modal
                            var modal = document.getElementById("modal[[${object.id}]]");
                            
                            // Get the button that opens the modal
                            var btn = document.getElementById("openModal[[${object.id}]]");
                            
                            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
                            
                            // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
                            btn.onclick = function() {
                              modal.style.display = "block";
                            }
                            
                            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                            span.onclick = function() {
                              modal.style.display = "none";
                            }
                            
                            // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
                            window.onclick = function(event) {
                              if (event.target == modal) {
                                modal.style.display = "none";
                              }
                            }
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #4F60FF;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  from {top: -300px; opacity: 0} 
  to {top: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {top: -300px; opacity: 0}
  to {top: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<div th:each="object:${listObjects}">
  <button th:id="'openModal' + ${object.id}">Open modal</button>
  <div th:id="'modal' + ${object.id}" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">Some text...</div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3 th:text="${object.name}"></h3>
        <p>Some text...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution or still wondering why this wouldn't work? Basically your JS should work with `id` set by Thymeleaf. Right now it is hardcoded by Thymeleaf to the last `id` of the list. You should not use Thymeleaf in your JS code, instead just dynamically query selector based on the `id` beginning, ex: "openModal" and "modal".

Comment: At the end I switched to bootstrap modal and I used th:attr to set dynamically each modal. Anyway I solved even if I had to use bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

The button that opens modal has different id wrt modal id

Try changing

```
<div th:id="'modal' + ${object.id}" class="modal">
```

to

```
<div th:id="'openModal' + ${object.id}" class="modal">
```